# Is this a correct way to query a varchar date type in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have table whose structure is `describe table`:

```
bundle  varchar(128)    NO  MUL     
deleted tinyint(4)  NO  PRI 0   
entity_id   int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI NULL    
revision_id int(10) unsigned    NO  MUL NULL    
langcode    varchar(32) NO  PRI     
delta   int(10) unsigned    NO  PRI NULL    
date_value  varchar(20) NO  MUL NULL
```

Date value are saved in the `2021-01-01` format.
I am trying to query it for anything less than a particular date. For example:

```
select count(*) from table where table.date_value < '2021-01-05' order by table.date_value DES
```

This seems to be working as the range of records I am getting is within the correct range and the most recent (largest) date is 2021-01-04. but I hesitant to rely on this unless I know for sure it's a proper mechanism.

If this is correct, how does mysql do the comparison? Does it convert dates internally to timestamps?

Comment: You should make the `date_value` column a proper `date` or `datetime` column.  Do _not_ store your dates as text.

Comment: Technically, in your statement you are comparing a string to a string .... the database engine may be doing some conversion of its own, depending on its own engine rules.  If you want to ensure that it's definitely doing date comparisons, then just add CONVERT() for your column and your date string.   (Or, as Tim suggests, get your source data column to the correct data type, and you'll have one less thing to worry about ....)

Comment: @tim sure.. I agree. I'd love to do that but this is a problem for another day. craig how does < operator work on strings?

Comment: Your query should work, q.v. my answer below.

Comment: There are **so many** questions here about MySQL date handling, and the problem almost always starts with a `date` or `datetime` value stored as a string. However painful changing is now, not changing will be worse in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, the `date_value` column should be `date` or `datetime` type.  Given that this is not a possibility for you, your current approach should be fine.  This assumes that all text dates are stored in the format `YYYY-mm-dd`, which is an ISO format.  If so, then your comparison against a string literal with the same format should work.

Comment: thanks for you answer. any refernces on how the `<` `>` operators work correctly on a varchar type?

Comment: Inequality checks should also work, assuming that the text dates are all in the same ISO format.